# DHCP server not dynamic updating DNS across multiple domains

Tags: windows, active-directory, dhcp, migration, internal-dns

I am in the process of migrating from an old single label domain to to a new domain on a new server. I have just switched over to the DHCP server on the new domain however, computers still on the old company domain are not being added to either DNS from the DHCP server.

```
Old Domain: company
    DNS Server (company primary zone, A.company.com stub zone)

New Domain: A.company.com
    DNS Server (A.company.com primary zone, company secondary zone)
    DHCP Server
```

Both DNS have reverse lookups zones for the DHCP range. I originally had stub zones setup for the other domain in each DNS, but switched the new domain to a secondary zone for company domain hoping that would help things. I also created a service account on the A.company.com domain which is used by the DHCP server and has permissions to write in both DNS. The domains are setup with a two-way trust.

Also tried using conditional forwarders instead of stub/secondary zones in the A.company.com DNS. Still getting having this issue.

The DHCP log on the DHCP server has the following error:

```
Forward record registration for IPv4 address [[X.X.X.X]] and FQDN <ComputerName>.company failed with error SERV_FAIL. This is likely to be because the forward lookup zone for this record does not exist on the DNS server.
```

Comment: The clients need to be reconfigured to register records in the new domain name.

Comment: All clients will eventually be migrated to the new domain, however I am looking for a stopgap until that can happen. One issue that I am running into is that the Active Directory Migration Tool that I am using to migrate workstations can not find the computers because their new address leases do not exist in either DNS.